# Animate string (character by character) doesn't appear on UITextView during animate

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, jquery-animate, uitextview

I'm trying to animate an NSString and make it appear character by character.
While I see in NSLog the function did work, but the text doesn't appear on the UITExtView during animation, only when animation ends.

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startAnimation) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

#pragma mark - General Methods

- (void)animateCharacterByCharacter_text:(NSString *)text characterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)characterDelay
{
    [self.textAbout setText:@""];

    for (int i=0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        NSString *textToSet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%c", self.textAbout.text, [text characterAtIndex:i]];
        self.textAbout.text = textToSet;

        NSLog(@"%@", textToSet);

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:characterDelay];
    }
}

- (void)startAnimation
{
    NSString *stringAbout = @"sfhasdf\nhajsbdh";
    [self animateCharacterByCharacter_text:stringAbout characterDelay:0.5];
}
```

I've been trying also with 'dispatch_async' and I get the same results.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `sleepForTimeInterval:` as it prevents the UI from updating. Instead, run a timer and each time it fires add the next character to the text field ( and cancel the timer when done).